# viewmodel not binding from angular [5] to dotnet core mvc route

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I'm trying to bind a viewmodel containing an input file and another property to an mvc route but whatever I try has resulted in failure (no errors, just null values when the route is called).

#### c# viewmodel

```
      public class TdaFileUploadRequest
      {
        public long TdaId { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
      }
```

#### angular component form

```
   <form #fileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addFile()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group select-group">
                <label class="control-label col-form-label">TDA</label>
                <select name="profile" [(ngModel)]="selectedTda" (ngModelChange)="selectTdaItem(selectedTda)">
                    <option *ngFor="let tda of tdaSelectItems" [ngValue]="tda.id">
                        {{ tda.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row margin-tspace-10">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input #fileInput class="form-control" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-tspace-10">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload File</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### angular component

only showing pertinent code. `result` of `.subscribe(result =>` is undefined when stepping through...a timing issue? I'm subscribing to the observable in the service...I think.

```
  addFile(form: NgForm): void {

    try {
        const fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

        if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {
            const fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
            let status = "Not Set";
            let message = "File uploaded successfully!";

            let tdaFileUploadRequest = {
                tdaId: this.selectedTda,
                file: fileToUpload
            };

            this.tdaFileService
                .uploadFile(tdaFileUploadRequest)
                .subscribe(result => {
                     if (result) {
                        status = result['status'] || 'status not available';
                        message = result['message'] || 'no messages';
                    }

                    if (status === errorStatus) {
                        this.showError(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.showSuccess(message);
                    }

                }, error => this.handleError(error));
        }  
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e || 'file-upload.component error');
    } 

}
```

#### angular service

I tried setting the header options as well but that did not help. The values are as expected to this point as well.

..setting the headers (but then I removed the following:
`let headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });`

```
      uploadFile(formData: any): Observable<any> {
          let uploadResult: any;
          const input = new FormData();
          input.append("tdaId", formData.tdaId);
          input.append("file", formData.file);

     return this.httpClient.post<IUploadResult>(this.baseUrl + 'api/TdaFile/UploadTdaFile', formData);

   }
```

And finally the mvc route. The route is called as expected but `tdaFileUploadRequest` is null

```
  [HttpPost("[action]")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadTdaFile([FromBody] TdaFileUploadRequest tdaFileUploadRequest)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: action should explicitly say where it wants the data from using `[FromBody]` attribute. i.e: `UploadTdaFile([FromBody]TdaFileUploadRequest tdaFileUploadRequest)`

Comment: @Nkosi I believe I tried that but will give it another shot. Thanks!

Comment: You could use Fiddler or Chrome Developer tools if the data is coming through and if so what section of the request does it appear on

Comment: You need the [FromBody] attribute on the parameter in your controller. Also, you may want to share the whole class so we can see if the path is correct. Does your method get called if you try it manually (curl or postman) ?

Comment: @Adrian `[FromBody]` didn't help, I have a break point in the route - it is called but the param is null